# How to get context in JUnit4

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4, android-context

I have a class:

```
public class Unit {

    private int id;
    private String unit;
    private String dimension;
    private Float factor;

    private Context ctx;


    public Unit(Context context){ this.ctx = context; }

    public Unit(String unit, String dimension, Float factor, Context context) {
        super();
        this.ctx = context;
        setUnit(unit);
        setDimension(dimension);
        setFactor(factor);
    }

    public void setDimension(String d) {
        String[] dimensions = ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dimensions_array);

        if(!Arrays.asList(dimensions).contains(d)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dimension is not one of the permittable dimension names");
    }

        this.dimension = d;
    }
                     ...
}
```

In order to validate "String dimension" against a string-array in strings.xml, I need to call getResources() and for this I need a context (this is the only reason I have context in this class.)

This works fine in the app, but now I want to write JUnit4 tests for class Unit and would want to call Unit(), for instance something like:

```
public class UnitTest {
    Unit unit;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Setting up ...");

        unit = new Unit("dm","length", (float) 0.1,some_context); // What context should I put here?
    }

    @Test
                          ...

}
```

How do I get a context into the class UnitTest? Or should I somehow rewrite the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class UnitTest {
    @Mock private Context context;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        when(context.doStuff()).thenReturn("stuff");
        unit = new Unit("dm","length", (float) 0.1, context);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not sure I understand the "doStuff-thenReturn" part.If I leave that one out (can I?), I get a NPE on the line "unit= new Unit(...)" which is due to "String [] dimensions = ctx.getResources()..." in the setDimension() method.  I also tried to call "MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);" in init() as I read somewhere that that's required.

Comment: 1. If you use `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` you don't need `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`

Comment: 2. `when(context.doStuff()).thenReturn("stuff");` is showing how to mock an interaction with the mock object. In this case I'm assuming you want to mock a method called `doStuff()`. It looks like you want to change this to `when(context.getResources()).thenReturn(new String[] { ... });`

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I actually used `when(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dimensions_array)).thenReturn(new String [] {"length", "mass", "volume"});` and also had to change the mocked context to `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) private Context context;` because I have a chained stub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Mock object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) configured with a mocking library of your choice, eg. [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).

Comment: Thanks. Could you be a bit more explicit, as I am just a beginner?